# Creating object literal fails in observable notebook

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I'm trying to run this simple code snippet from O'Reilly's "Learning React" book in an Observable notebook (https://observablehq.com/).

It works if I run it in the Chrome console (I can define the object and then run `tahoe.print()`), but if I try to run it in Observable I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected Token` when running the cell.

Is there something strange about Observable that prevents me from creating object literals like this?

```
tahoe = {
  resorts: ["Kirkwood","Squaw","Alpine"],
  print: function(delay=1000) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.resorts.join(", "))
    }, delay)
  }
}
```

Here's the notebook with the code: https://observablehq.com/@jritch/simple-snippet-breaks-in-observable

Comment: Just hover the magic wand to know why, and click it to fix your code: https://imgur.com/a/0EhYw9r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blex pointed out that to get this to work you need to wrap the object in parentheses:

```
tahoe = ({
  resorts: ["Kirkwood","Squaw","Alpine"],
  print: function(delay=1000) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.resorts.join(", "))
    }, delay)
  }
})
```

[Working snippet](https://observablehq.com/@jritch/simple-snippet-works-in-observable).

For a fuller explanation of why this is, [see this blogpost that outlines the differences between Observable and vanilla javascript](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observables-not-javascript):

> **Statements need curly braces, and return (or yield).** A cell body can be a simple expression, such as a number or string literal, or a
>   function call. But sometimes you want statements, such as for loops.
>   For that you’ll need curly braces, and a return statement to give the
>   cell a value. Think of a cell as a function, except the function has
>   no arguments. For the same reason, you’ll need to wrap object literals
>   in parentheses, or use a block statement with a return.

There's also a (somewhat difficult to see) magic wand widget that comes up beside the play button icon for the cell, that will automatically fix this issue if you click it:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/uf5H1LA.png]